# Beautifulsoup, urllib2 and requests did not find all HTML tags from 9gag.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to scrape 9gag comment section to do some sentiment analysis and label the post as positive or negative. The ultimate goal is to train the data of thousands of posts and the predict the sentiment of the post based on Comment count, post upvotes, top ten ten comment upvotes, and the title of the post.

I successfully scraped the hot section for titles and upvotes but when it comes to scraping comments, the Html parser wont show the relevant tags. I tried different libraries like BS4, Requests, Pattern, urllib1/2. I even tried 'html.parser' instead of lxml.

My question is 9gag comment section restricted from scraping? if not, Is there any reason why any of the parser is not able to get all the tags?

Update #2-
Here's the code that I used-

```
    url = URL("http://9gag.com/gag/a1Mzz1D")
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"comment-embed"})
```

the output looks like and empty list- [ ]

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of your code and their output? Also, do you know if you're getting an exception or just empty output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded using React but you can do a little bit of parsing and get all the data you need in *json* format:

```
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin
import ast

base = "http://9gag.com/"

# these are the params to get the json.
params = {"appId": "",
          "url": "",
          "count": "10",
          "level": "2",
          "order": "score",
          "mentionMapping": "true",
          "origin": "9gag.com"}

js = "Request URL:http://comment-cdn.9gag.com/v1/cacheable/comment-list.json"

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.get(base)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    # links to each actual page.
    links = [urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("a.badge-evt.point"")]
    for link in links:
        cont = s.get(link).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont,"lxml")
        # the params are all in the script body
        script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('appId')).text
        # convert to dict so we can pull what we need by key
        data = ast.literal_eval(script[script.find("{"):script.rfind("}") + 1])
        params["appId"] = data["appId"]
        params["url"] = data["url"]
        page_json = s.get(js, params=params).json()
        for dct in page_json["payload"]["comments"]:
            print(dct)
```

If we run that code just using the first url returned, we get:

```
In [28]: with requests.session() as s:
   ....:         r = s.get(base)
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
   ....:         links = [urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("a.comment.badge-evt")][:1]
   ....:         for link in links:
   ....:                 cont = s.get(link).content
   ....:                 soup = BeautifulSoup(cont,"lxml")
   ....:                 script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('appId')).text
   ....:                 data = ast.literal_eval(script[script.find("{"):script.rfind("}") + 1])
   ....:                 params["appId"] = data["appId"]
   ....:                 params["url"] = data["url"]
   ....:                 page_json = s.get(js, params=params).json()
   ....:                 for dct in page_json["payload"]["comments"]:
   ....:                         print(dct)
   ....:             
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'This is so awkward to watch ... and funny', u'userId': u'u_13759018032623', u'likeCount': 343, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000004834_14651297124662', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@twistedpickle.and also fake.', u'userId': u'u_145548331532421082', u'likeCount': 26, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@twistedpickle.and also fake.', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@twistedpickle': u'aBL7q1'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513113612585611', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146512971246623391', u'timestamp': 1465131136, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'savage_ali', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/34323189_100_45.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1455483315', u'userId': u'u_145548331532421082', u'hashedAccountId': u'anbN66n', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/savage_ali'}, u'accountId': u'34323189', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513113612585611', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@twistedpickle.and also fake.', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'This is so awkward to watch ... and funny', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146512971246623391', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465129712, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'twistedpickle', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/1870095_100_1.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1375901803', u'userId': u'u_13759018032623', u'hashedAccountId': u'aBL7q1', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/twistedpickle'}, u'accountId': u'1870095', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146512971246623391', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'This is so awkward to watch ... and funny', u'childrenTotal': 19, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'Hahaha PANTURA', u'userId': u'u_143454521023534763', u'likeCount': 231, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000004076_14649387351969', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@deadfight nussittuna nukut paremmin', u'userId': u'u_141790386790069041', u'likeCount': 39, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@deadfight nussittuna nukut paremmin', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@deadfight': u'aYLgpy7'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513018381635287', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493873519691145', u'timestamp': 1465130183, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'lady_kappa', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/22251683_100_38.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1417903867', u'userId': u'u_141790386790069041', u'hashedAccountId': u'a5K8b5N', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/lady_kappa'}, u'accountId': u'22251683', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513018381635287', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@deadfight nussittuna nukut paremmin', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'Hahaha PANTURA', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146493873519691145', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1464938735, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'deadfight', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/27180133_100_2.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1434545210', u'userId': u'u_143454521023534763', u'hashedAccountId': u'aYLgpy7', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/deadfight'}, u'accountId': u'27180133', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146493873519691145', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'Hahaha PANTURA', u'childrenTotal': 16, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/oMJ28xM_700wa_0.gif', u'userId': u'u_141680114571912397', u'likeCount': 225, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000003373_14649381081078', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@shogun_ka_yo up you go', u'userId': u'u_144283683005248817', u'likeCount': 2, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@shogun_ka_yo up you go', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@shogun_ka_yo': u'aMQRLRW'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513150738658348', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493810810784782', u'timestamp': 1465131507, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'dergermanyball', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/29998985_100_29.jpg', u'timestamp': u'', u'userId': u'u_144283683005248817', u'hashedAccountId': u'a1dpXrY', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/dergermanyball'}, u'accountId': u'29998985', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513150738658348', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@shogun_ka_yo up you go', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/oMJ28xM_700wa_0.gif', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146493810810784782', u'type': u'media', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1464938108, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'embedImage': {u'type': u'ANIMATED', u'image': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/287e9c03142644331422775855_700w_0.jpg', u'width': 400, u'height': 206}, u'animated': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/287e9c03142644331422775855_700wa_0.gif', u'width': 400, u'height': 206}, u'video': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/287e9c03142644331422775855_700wv_0.mp4', u'width': 400, u'height': 206}}}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'shogun_ka_yo', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/22391718_100_2.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1416801145', u'userId': u'u_141680114571912397', u'hashedAccountId': u'aMQRLRW', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/shogun_ka_yo'}, u'accountId': u'22391718', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 1, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146493810810784782', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'[url]http://i.memeful.com/media/post/oMJ28xM_700wa_0.gif[/url]', u'childrenTotal': 4, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'Now imagine if the genders were reversed', u'userId': u'u_143552720523387146', u'likeCount': 179, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000003144_14651301155438', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@rednotash hush little one. You&#039;re making sense now', u'userId': u'u_141363015125977644', u'likeCount': 77, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@rednotash hush little one. You&#039;re making sense now', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@rednotash': u'aOv8RMy'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513114535963914', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146513011554386056', u'timestamp': 1465131145, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'srslydude', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_59_100_v0.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1413630151', u'userId': u'u_141363015125977644', u'hashedAccountId': u'aYwvpZx', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/srslydude'}, u'accountId': u'21558777', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513114535963914', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@rednotash hush little one. You&#039;re making sense now', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'Now imagine if the genders were reversed', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146513011554386056', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465130115, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'rednotash', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/27823975_100_5.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1435527205', u'userId': u'u_143552720523387146', u'hashedAccountId': u'aOv8RMy', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/rednotash'}, u'accountId': u'27823975', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513011554386056', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'Now imagine if the genders were reversed', u'childrenTotal': 9, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'Never let your waif follow you? Well she wouldnt follow you if you werent a dickhead. Women have the sixth sense . We know whats going on.', u'userId': u'u_145321627176216569', u'likeCount': 78, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000002462_14651303108023', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@marshmallowww What if I tell you that gender has nothing to do with it? Men have that &quot;sixth sense&quot; too.', u'userId': u'u_143741207696358239', u'likeCount': 56, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@marshmallowww What if I tell you that gender has nothing to do with it? Men have that &quot;sixth sense&quot; too.', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@marshmallowww': u'ab693MB'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513102333226094', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146513031080236628', u'timestamp': 1465131023, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'the_hidden', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/28267060_100_15.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1437412076', u'userId': u'u_143741207696358239', u'hashedAccountId': u'aop4wG2', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/the_hidden'}, u'accountId': u'28267060', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513102333226094', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@marshmallowww What if I tell you that gender has nothing to do with it? Men have that &quot;sixth sense&quot; too.', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'Never let your waif follow you? Well she wouldnt follow you if you werent a dickhead. Women have the sixth sense . We know whats going on.', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146513031080236628', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465130310, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'marshmallowww', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/33477821_100_134.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1453216271', u'userId': u'u_145321627176216569', u'hashedAccountId': u'ab693MB', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/marshmallowww'}, u'accountId': u'33477821', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513031080236628', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'Never let your waif follow you? Well she wouldnt follow you if you werent a dickhead. Women have the sixth sense . We know whats going on.', u'childrenTotal': 20, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'But is correct that she can hit him? i mean, &quot;no violence&quot; right? if SHE is drunk and doing stupid things, and the husband go and hit her, is correct too? because equality.', u'userId': u'u_143329792027606743', u'likeCount': 54, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000001796_14651298735006', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@pcmasteracer yes it&#039;s correct', u'userId': u'u_143073218849877360', u'likeCount': 9, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@pcmasteracer yes it&#039;s correct', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@pcmasteracer': u'avnOvdq'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513013516459530', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146512987350064451', u'timestamp': 1465130135, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'kkakuka97', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/26450856_100_3.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1430732188', u'userId': u'u_143073218849877360', u'hashedAccountId': u'a4j4NWy', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/kkakuka97'}, u'accountId': u'26450856', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513013516459530', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@pcmasteracer yes it&#039;s correct', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'But is correct that she can hit him? i mean, &quot;no violence&quot; right? if SHE is drunk and doing stupid things, and the husband go and hit her, is correct too? because equality.', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146512987350064451', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465129873, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'pcmasteracer', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_62_100_v0.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1433297920', u'userId': u'u_143329792027606743', u'hashedAccountId': u'avnOvdq', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/pcmasteracer'}, u'accountId': u'27225255', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146512987350064451', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'But is correct that she can hit him? i mean, &quot;no violence&quot; right? if SHE is drunk and doing stupid things, and the husband go and hit her, is correct too? because equality.', u'childrenTotal': 7, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'I can hear the &#039;BONG!&#039;', u'userId': u'u_13987497367750', u'likeCount': 30, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000001168_14650124142865', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@yajirobe__ but not boing', u'userId': u'u_13775281935884', u'likeCount': 4, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@yajirobe__ but not boing', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@yajirobe__': u'avgE1Y5'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513060674619430', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146501241428653553', u'timestamp': 1465130606, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'siophang', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/11455251_100_2.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1377528193', u'userId': u'u_13775281935884', u'hashedAccountId': u'aBQK6qO', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/siophang'}, u'accountId': u'11455251', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513060674619430', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@yajirobe__ but not boing', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'I can hear the &#039;BONG!&#039;', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146501241428653553', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465012414, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'yajirobe__', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/16992199_100_5.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1398749736', u'userId': u'u_13987497367750', u'hashedAccountId': u'avgE1Y5', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/yajirobe__'}, u'accountId': u'16992199', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146501241428653553', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'I can hear the &#039;BONG!&#039;', u'childrenTotal': 1, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/PRoPBdo_700wa_0.gif', u'userId': u'u_13907047642371', u'likeCount': 21, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000000967_14649476233018', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@kaylaruffalo mfw', u'userId': u'u_13907047642371', u'likeCount': 0, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@kaylaruffalo mfw', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@kaylaruffalo': u'adYKGQj'}, u'commentId': u'c_146494763324897147', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146494762330186947', u'timestamp': 1464947633, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'kaylaruffalo', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/16005886_100_9.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1390704764', u'userId': u'u_13907047642371', u'hashedAccountId': u'adYKGQj', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/kaylaruffalo'}, u'accountId': u'16005886', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146494763324897147', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@kaylaruffalo mfw', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/PRoPBdo_700wa_0.gif', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146494762330186947', u'type': u'media', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1464947623, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'embedImage': {u'type': u'ANIMATED', u'image': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/872be169144077120242844098_700w_0.jpg', u'width': 500, u'height': 400}, u'animated': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/872be169144077120242844098_700wa_0.gif', u'width': 500, u'height': 400}, u'video': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/872be169144077120242844098_700wv_0.mp4', u'width': 500, u'height': 400}}}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'kaylaruffalo', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/16005886_100_9.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1390704764', u'userId': u'u_13907047642371', u'hashedAccountId': u'adYKGQj', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/kaylaruffalo'}, u'accountId': u'16005886', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 1, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146494762330186947', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'[url]http://i.memeful.com/media/post/PRoPBdo_700wa_0.gif[/url]', u'childrenTotal': 1, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'Look at the dude in the red shirt run XD', u'userId': u'u_144176454299618603', u'likeCount': 15, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000000806_14651298710300', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@crazybrownguy he knew he was next', u'userId': u'u_13976607580627', u'likeCount': 1, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@crazybrownguy he knew he was next', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@crazybrownguy': u'agGWL5q'}, u'commentId': u'c_146514413390208345', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146512987103009031', u'timestamp': 1465144133, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'lightfoot2012', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/17248879_100_6.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1397660758', u'userId': u'u_13976607580627', u'hashedAccountId': u'axZPvbp', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/lightfoot2012'}, u'accountId': u'17248879', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146514413390208345', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@crazybrownguy he knew he was next', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'Look at the dude in the red shirt run XD', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146512987103009031', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465129871, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'crazybrownguy', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/29662036_100_10.jpg', u'timestamp': u'1441764542', u'userId': u'u_144176454299618603', u'hashedAccountId': u'agGWL5q', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/crazybrownguy'}, u'accountId': u'29662036', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146512987103009031', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'Look at the dude in the red shirt run XD', u'childrenTotal': 1, u'isAnonymous': 0}
{u'hasNext': True, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/kRp6z2w_700wa_0.gif', u'userId': u'u_144337172763285563', u'likeCount': 5, u'orderKey': u'score_00000000000626_14651301539010', u'children': [{u'hasNext': False, u'dislikeCount': 0, u'text': u'@wat_ya_doin I agree with that wife', u'userId': u'u_144337172763285563', u'likeCount': 3, u'children': [], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'@wat_ya_doin I agree with that wife', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'@wat_ya_doin': u'ay8yRoM'}, u'commentId': u'c_146513018506335085', u'type': u'text', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146513015390105680', u'timestamp': 1465130185, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'dummy': []}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'wat_ya_doin', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/29948571_100_6.jpg', u'timestamp': u'', u'userId': u'u_144337172763285563', u'hashedAccountId': u'ay8yRoM', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/wat_ya_doin'}, u'accountId': u'29948571', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 0, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513018506335085', u'level': 2, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'@wat_ya_doin I agree with that wife', u'childrenTotal': 0, u'isAnonymous': 0}], u'isCollapsed': 0, u'mediaText': u'http://i.memeful.com/media/post/kRp6z2w_700wa_0.gif', u'section': u'', u'mentionMapping': {u'dummy': u''}, u'commentId': u'c_146513015390105680', u'type': u'media', u'status': 0, u'parent': u'c_146493707813378457', u'timestamp': 1465130153, u'embedMediaMeta': {u'embedImage': {u'type': u'ANIMATED', u'image': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/be90178a145186181304494323_700w_0.jpg', u'width': 319, u'height': 260}, u'animated': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/be90178a145186181304494323_700wa_0.gif', u'width': 319, u'height': 260}, u'video': {u'url': u'http://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/be90178a145186181304494323_700wv_0.mp4', u'width': 318, u'height': 260}}}, u'user': {u'displayName': u'wat_ya_doin', u'avatarUrl': u'http://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/29948571_100_6.jpg', u'timestamp': u'', u'userId': u'u_144337172763285563', u'hashedAccountId': u'ay8yRoM', u'profileUrls': {u'a_dd8f2b7d304a10edaf6f29517ea0ca4100a43d1b': u'http://9gag.com/u/wat_ya_doin'}, u'accountId': u'29948571', u'permissions': []}, u'isUrl': 1, u'isLike': {u'value': 0}, u'permalink': u'http://9gag.com/gag/a4YM4n1#cs_comment_id=c_146513015390105680', u'level': 1, u'suppData': {}, u'richtext': u'[url]http://i.memeful.com/media/post/kRp6z2w_700wa_0.gif[/url]', u'childrenTotal': 3, u'isAnonymous': 0}
```

As an example we can pull the text from *dct* then iterate over the `dct["children"]` to get more comments:

```
In [30]: params = {"appId": "",
   ....:           "url": "",
   ....:           "count": "2",
   ....:           "level": "2",
   ....:           "order": "score",
   ....:           "mentionMapping": "true",
   ....:           "origin": "9gag.com"}

In [31]: js = "Request URL:http://comment-cdn.9gag.com/v1/cacheable/comment-list.json"

In [32]: with requests.session() as s:
   ....:         r = s.get(base)
   ....:         soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
   ....:         links = [urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("a.badge-evt.point")][:1]
   ....:         for link in links:
   ....:                 cont = s.get(link).content
   ....:                 soup = BeautifulSoup(cont,"lxml")
   ....:                 script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile('appId')).text
   ....:                 data = ast.literal_eval(script[script.find("{"):script.rfind("}") + 1])
   ....:                 params["appId"] = data["appId"]
   ....:                 params["url"] = data["url"]
   ....:                 page_json = s.get(js, params=params).json()
   ....:                 for dct in page_json["payload"]["comments"]:
   ....:                         print(dct["text"])
   ....:                         for child in dct["children"]:
   ....:                                 print(child["text"])
   ....:                 

Once again this is a post made by someone who has no idea what true love is. True love is jealous, painful, and difficult. It&#039;s a battle it always will be. You&#039;re either fighting yourself to be a better person, fighting life to give the other person the life they deserve or fighting the other person. But true love is worth all of it, its also beautiful, kind, gentle and warm.  No relationship is perfect. There is not &quot;8 ways to know&quot;. The one for you is the one who will put up with your shit but at the same time make you want to make yourself a better person. Your true love will get on your nerves, piss you off, hurt you, but they will also love you, hold you up when you can&#039;t and forgive you. True love is when you find someone you can stand beside through anything, someone who would never want to hurt you  When you find someone you can trust no matter what. No one is perfect and there is more than one person in the world you can fall in love with, but when you find that person, you fi
@celticdraconian this Is so true
Comment complaining that this will lead straight to the &quot;friendzone&quot;
Comment saying the &quot;Friendzone&quot; is not a thing.
```

You can see I changed the param count to be 2, to get all the data you can set it to a really high number like `"count":"1000"` to get all the data you would if you kept loading more comments on the page:

Answer (score 1):

Their comments are loaded via [reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html), you'll need something that executes javascript in order to scrape the comments section.

A few to get you started:

- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)
- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
- [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (makes it easier to use selenium, plus
  some extra features

)